# Concatenating root text to subnodes in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, grammar

In part of my grammar I can put parts in common of some paths in evidence and in parenthesis put the rest of the path that is different between them, like:

foo.bar(A;B;woo.C) is the representation of 3 paths: foo.bar.A, foo.bar.B and foo.bar.woo.C

Given funcPaths, I need to create an AST tree with those 3 nodes with the complete path, so for that I tried the following

```
funcPaths
  : f1=field c1=fieldList[$f1.text] -> ^(LIST_PATH $c1)
  ;

fieldList[String s] 
  : '(' p+=part[s] ( ';' p+=part[s] )* ')' -> $p+
  ;

part[String s]
  : FIELD_ID -> { new CommonTree(new CommonToken(FIELD_ID, s + "." + $FIELD_ID.text))}
  ;

field
  : FIELD_ID
  ;
```

I would expect a subtree with LIST_PATH as root and 3 subnodes: foo.bar.A, foo.bar.B and foo.bar.woo.C of type FIELD_ID, but on ANTLRWorks it draws the tree with just the root, LIST_PATH, that means that those subnodes are not being created, but if I change to

```
  part[String s]
      : FIELD_ID -> FIELD_ID
      ;
```

I get the 3 subnodes drawn, but that doesn't solve my problem of concatenating the common part to the individual parts.

So my question is: how can I solve my issue of building those nodes that are a concatenation of the subtree root and the nodes? I don't necessarily need to use the hardcoded commontree creation as long as I can produce those nodes

Comment: which version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: @monty0 v3 and antlrworks 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this?

```
part[String s]
  : FIELD_ID -> FIELD_ID {$FIELD_ID.setText(s + "." + $FIELD_ID.text);}
  ;
```

I can't speak to why your solution doesn't work.  Just glancing at it it seems OK.

Comment: error: 'void' type not allowed here
[08:53:26]       adaptor.addChild(root_0, FIELD_ID45.setText(s + "." + (FIELD_ID45!=null?FIELD_ID45.getText():null)));

Comment: Hmm, it thinks the action is supposed to produce a child instead of just doing something on its own.  I'll have to browse the manual/book to figure out if what I was suggesting is possible.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this in ANTLRWorks, but your fragment isn't enough to get me going.  If you could post a complete .g file and sample input as a GIST or something, then I could just load up and run it and debug from there.  Unfortunately the problem isn't obvious to me.  Creating the CommonTree should be working, I cribbed that example from the book.